# Nap after exercising

Tags: workout, sleep

I'm a grad student I find it hard to concentrate on my work after exercising (cardio+weights) and I can only do after taking a nap. 
I would like to know if its healthy to have a nap after the work outs?

Comment: Healthy in what sense? Are you asking if it improves your recovery?

Comment: Yes, I want to to know if it will affect the recovery and improve the overall fitness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Exercise also causes [CNS (Central Nervous System) fatigue](http://www.myosynthesis.com/the-limits-in-your-head)**

In a similar manner that your muscles/joints need to recover your CNS requires recovery as well.

Extended CNS fatigue (ie > week is a key sign of overtraining). If you feel 'fried' get more sleep or take a break for a bit.

Sleep, eating more calories, and reducing external stress should help.

Here's a link for [some additional tips](http://jasonferruggia.com/7-ways-to-minimize-cns-fatigue/) to adjust your workouts for additional relief. Basically, it comes down to two things. Either don't do everything to the max all the time and/or or schedule for ample recovery (ie sleep/relaxation).

Answer (score 2):

Naps help the learning process, the brain sorts out the stuff you've learned.  Napping and studying go hand in hand.  Likewise, rest after exercise helps the learning process too.

All in all, nap if you feel you want to, it'll only have good affects on both your fitness and your studies.

Comment: "rest after exercise helps the learning process too" - A lot of people forget that exercise is as much about learning how to control your physical movements as it is about burning calories or developing muscles.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, you are no the only one who had this issue, so did I when I first started out my workout sessions, but now after 2 months of continuous workouts, my brain and body has fine tuned itself to accept the strain during the work outs. In short, you'll get used to it, and you will able to study without naps in the long run. 
Sleep when ever your body feels so, dont fight against your body because you will only be hurting yourself.
Keep working out and stay fit!

Comment: I disagree. I've been running for 11 years and I still feel like a nap after a solid workout. If you aren't tired, you aren't challenging yourself.